# epplus/excel writing to a cell with more than one character

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm experiencing some difficulties with writing to excel cells using EPPLUS library. I can perfectly write values to cells with range from A to Z, but not to AA and so on. So my question is: how can I write to cells where cell address contains more than one letter. What if for example product code that comes from "Product_row" range has B7:AA7 address. I have tried R1C1 notation but don't get the right string format.

Here is my code:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFileName))
{

    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[Worksheet_Name];

    //Make a new list with Product name and pallet count
    foreach (var item in paletInfo.PaletDefinitions)
    {
        pList.Add(new Data { pName = item.ProductName.Trim(), pCount = item.ProductCounter });
    }

    #region Fill Product and Palet count
    foreach (var col in sheet.Names.First(c => c.Name == "Product_row"))
    {
        var itemGroup = pList.GroupBy(i => i.pName).Select(g => new { pName = g.Key, TotalQty = g.Select(j => j.pCount).Sum() });
        var range = col.Address;
        var queryResult = itemGroup.FirstOrDefault(c => c.pName == sheet.Cells[range].Text);
        if (queryResult == null) continue;

        var value = queryResult.TotalQty;
        range = range.Substring(0, 1) + (Convert.ToInt32(range.Substring(1)) + 10 + actualDay - 2);

        sheet.Cells[range].Value = value;
    }
    #endregion

    sheet.Cells["AA1"].Value = actualMonth;
    sheet.Cells["AI1"].Value = actualYear;

    try
    {
        package.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Info(e.Message);
        Logger.Error(e, $"Excel Export: {e.Message}");
        mail.Send(Mail_Origin, Mail_Error, "error",$"Error when writing to Excel {nF} file, maybe file is still OPEN?");
    }
    Logger.Info("Excel_Export invoked");

}
```

Comment: The way you're writing works fine (`sheet.Cells["AA1"].Value="newValue"`), if it's not working for you, you have another problem. You could also reference the cell as `sheet.Cells[lineNumber,ColumnNumber]` and you can set the value of a cell as `sheet.SetValue(address,value)` or `sheet.SetValue(lineNumber, columnNumber,value)`

Comment: Please create [mcve]. I tried looking into this but got discouraged because there are variables which I don't know where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I could guide to 2 solutions.

**Solution 1:**
Use direct indexing.

```
sheet.Cells[rowIndex,columnIndex].Value = ActualMonth;
```

**Solution 2:**
Try updating your assemblies to latest version.